# Android GUI stack performance metrics

Tags: android, performance, metrics

We are evaluating different GUI frameworks for an embedded system. What I like to do is run a GUI program that does things like image alpha blending, draw text with different effects, fill rectangles etc and measure its CPU load during these operations.
Is anything like that done already for android GUI framework based application?

I appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Joe